# UITableView with UITextView scrolling issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have composed a tableview with some custom cells. Some of the custom cells contain `UIWebView`, some has `UISlider` plus `UITextField`, some has `UIButton`.

Now when I click on textfield which is uitableviewcell's subview at the bottom of the `UITableView`, **I can't manage to get my table cell properly visible above the keyboard.**

Using of `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController` is not possible for me. Because my UI structure is somewhat weird and dynamic. In simple way it is like

```
UIView -> UIScrollView with paging -> x number of UITableViews -> y number of UITableViewCell ->  z number of UITextFields, UISliders, UIWebViews, UIButtons, UILables, etc.
```

I have also tried below code to make it work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
    [table_Question[pageNumber] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[table_Question[pageNumber] indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

but it is not working :(

Thanks,

**EDIT 1:**

I have checked references for textfield, tableviewcell and tableview. So reference of object is not the problem.

Comment: Why aren't you just resizing the entire UIView, when the keyboard is visible?

Comment: Does textFieldDidBeginEditing:() method is firing or not?

Comment: @Lefteris: then I have to resize everything in that, I dont think this is good idea.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: yes ofcourse it is firing.

Comment: @CrimeMasterGOGO But you are using a UITableView (it doesn't matter that you are nesting it inside a scrollview). So resizing a UITableView, is not requiring you to do anything actually. It will just move the cells up, as you want to do so...

Comment: In textFieldDidBeginEditing() method, print the "cell" and see the result, wheather your getting the exact cell or not? And let us know...

Comment: @downVoter why downvote... show some guts to put a reason also....

Comment: @Lefteris: hmmm... I can give it a try...

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: yes, the same reference....

Comment: @CrimeMasterGOGO - did you checked the cell data by printing in textFieldDidBeginEditing() or not?

Comment: Now check table_Question[pageNumber] is the exact table where the cell is present or not, by checking the log of pageNumber? Because you have multiple tables in your scenario right?

Comment: @BhanuPrakash : Reference is not the problem, because I am performing some other operations using these references which works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27089/discussion-between-bhanu-prakash-and-crime-master-gogo)

Comment: [Have you tried this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6354426/1756131)

Comment: @MicRO -  updated my code. And the link which you have posted I saw now thanks...:-)

Comment: @BhanuPrakash I'm talking to the OP. I didn't try your code

Comment: @MicRO : did the trick... thank you so much... can you please post it as an answer so it may help someone else also..

Comment: You can update your question , providing information that you got it solved from the given link. No need to copy paste the same answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    UITableViewCell *aCell = [table_Question[pageNumber] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
    CGSize cellSize = aCell.frame.size;
    [table_Question[pageNumber] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, cellSize.height*2) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code....

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textField superview] superview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[table_Question[pageNumber] indexPathForCell:cell];

        int totalRows = 0;
        if([[table_Question[pageNumber] numberOfSections] > 1)
         {
              for(int i = 0; i<([indexPath.section] - 1);i++)
               {
                     totalRows += [[table_Question[pageNumber] numberOfRowsInSection:i];
                }
          }

          totalRows += indexPath.row;

        int  yPosition = totalRows * cell.frame.size.height;
        CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, yPosition);
        [[table_Question[pageNumber] setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
}
```

This will helps for you...

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you want to show the `UITextField` as well as the keyboard, when the user starts editing the `UITextField` inside the `UITableViewCell`.
If that's the case, you can set the `contentInset` of the `UITableView` to the required size and then just scroll to the required index path.

### Following is a sample code:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    @try
    {
        table_Question[pageNumber].contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat Req_top, CGFloat Req_left, CGFloat Req_bottom, CGFloat Req_right);
        [table_Question[pageNumber] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[table_Question[pageNumber] indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

        //Add this to you code to scroll in the tableview gets hidden by keyboard
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, Required_Height);
       [yourScrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the position of your tableview. If its at the bottom of the screen OR somewhere where the keyboard covers its view then you have to increase the "contentSize" of the scroll view also. Add this to your textfieldshouldBeginEditing

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0,Required_Height);
    [your_scrollview setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];'